# django rest framework writable nested serializer returns empty nested data

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm following this link (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) to write nested serializer.  But when I pop the 'vars' from validated_data in the create method of HostSerializer, I found it's empty.

I'm using django 1.9.2 and django restframework 3.3.2.

**My model:**

```
class Host(models.Model):

  name = CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
  vm_cpu = IntegerField(default=2)
  vm_mem = IntegerField(default=2048)
  create_vm = BooleanField(default=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return('%s' % (self.name))

class Variable(models.Model):

  name = CharField(max_length=10)
  value = CharField(max_length=20)
  host = models.ForeignKey(Host, related_name='vars')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return('%s=%s' % (self.name, self.value))
```

**Serializer**

```
class VariableSerializer(ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Variable

class HostSerializer(ModelSerializer):        

  vars = VariableSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Host

  def create(self, validated_data):

    # i set a break point here and found vars_data is empty
    vars_data = validated_data.pop('vars')
    host = Host.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for v in vars_data:
        Variable.objects.create(host = host, **v)

    return host
```

**This is the problem** I found vars_data is an empty list:

```
  def create(self, validated_data):

    # i set a break point here and found vars_data is empty
    vars_data = validated_data.pop('vars')
```

Here's the rest of the code

**admin.py**

```
class VariableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['name', 'value']

class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
  list_display = ['name']


admin.site.register(Variable, VariableAdmin)
admin.site.register(Host, HostAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'variables', VariableViewSet, base_name='variables')
router.register(r'hosts', HostViewSet, base_name='hosts')

urlpatterns = [
          url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
          ]
```

**views.py**

```
class VariableViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Variable.objects.all()
  serializer_class = VariableSerializer

class HostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Host.objects.all()
  serializer_class = HostSerializer
```

My test program

**post.py**

```
import json
import requests

file = 'host.json'
url = 'http://localhost:8001/test_nest/hosts/'

with open(file, 'r') as f:
  j = f.read()

data = json.loads(j)

r = requests.post(url, data = data)
print r.text
```

And here's the test data

**host.json**

```
{
"name": "host4",
"vars": [
    {
        "name": "var2-a",
        "value": "a1"
    },
    {
        "name": "var2-b",
        "value": "a2"
    }
],
"vm_cpu": 2,
"vm_mem": 2048,
"create_vm": true
}
```

I'm new to django.  So I'm wondering if it's something simple and obvious.  Did I use the wrong viewset?  Did I post to the wrong URL?  Or I setup the URL structure wrong?

Comment: Figured out the problem..

Comment: Figured out the problem.  In my post.py, I changed this line `r = requests.post(url, data = data)` to `r = requests.post(url, json = data)`.  I think it has to do w/ telling requests to take the content type as json. Note the json parameter to request is only available for requests version 2.4.6 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I your serializers try using...

```
def update(self, instance,validated_data):

    instance.vars_data = validated_data.get('vars',instance.vars)
    instance.host = Host.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for v in vars_data:
        v,created=Variable.objects.create(host = host, **v)
        instance.v.add(v)

    return host
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Maybe you can try it：

### models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    pass


class TobaccoCert(models.Model):
    license = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    license_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="certs", blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='cert image')
```

### views.py

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
   serializer_class = UserRegSerializer
   ...

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        # here i make my nested data `certs` and update it to data
        image_data = request.FILES.get('images')
        _license = data.get('username', None)
        certs = {'license': _license, 'license_image': image_data}
        data['certs'] = certs
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = self.perform_create(serializer)  # save it
        ret_dict = serializer.data
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
        ret_dict["token"] = jwt_encode_handler(payload)  # 获取token
        ret_dict["name"] = user.name if user.name else user.username
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(ret_dict, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

### serializer.py

```py
class CertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass


class UserRegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # [Serializer relations - Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)
    # this line is vars of your code
    certs = CertSerializer(many=True,write_only=True)
    ...
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}, help_text="passowrd", label="passowrd", write_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "mobile", "password", 'province', 'city', 'dist', 'code', 'certs')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        """
        # here we get certs
        certs_data = self.initial_data.get('certs')
        # just pop certs because it is useless for user create
        certs_empty = validated_data.pop('certs')
        user = super().create(validated_data=validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()
        # use certs data to create cert
        image_url = self.save_image(certs_data)
        _license = validated_data.get('username', None)
        TobaccoCert.objects.create(license=_license, license_image=image_url)
        return user
```

In short, you need to add your nested parameters directly in the request parameters. In my example code, it is certs which is `vars` in your example and then use `certs_data = self.initial_data.get('certs')` get the parameters you passed in `create` method.

Another possible way is post your data before your requests:
In postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzNBv.png)
in request:
[python - Django Rest Framework writable nested serializer with multiple nested objects - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466300/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializer-with-multiple-nested-objects)

In addition, you can try to modify queryDict directly. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930234/django-modifying-the-request-object/18931697) link and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247064/change-request-get-querydict-values)

### Some useful links

[django - Need help understanding many and source fields in a serializer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976679/need-help-understanding-many-and-source-fields-in-a-serializer/)

[python - Django rest framework writeable nested serializer data missing from validated_data - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175352/django-rest-framework-writeable-nested-serializer-data-missing-from-validated-da)