# Need help understanding many and source fields in a serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to familiarize myself with DRF and while going through a tutorial these serializers were used

```
class EmbeddedAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    votes = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'votes',)


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = EmbeddedAnswerSerializer(many=True,source='answer_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'answers', 'created_at', 'text', 'user_id',)
```

These are the models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My question is in the statement in the Question serializer

```
answers = EmbeddedAnswerSerializer(many=True,source='answer_set')
```

what is the purpose of `many = True` and `source='answer_set'` ?
I read from the documentation the following regarding `many=True`

> You can also still use the many=True argument to serializer classes.
> It's worth noting that many=True argument transparently creates a
> ListSerializer instance, allowing the validation logic for list and
> non-list data to be cleanly separated in the REST framework codebase.

I am confused by what that means? If I remove `many=True` from the code I get the error

```
AttributeError at /api/quest/1/2/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `text` on serializer `EmbeddedAnswerSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'text'.
```

Can anyone explain what `many=True` does and what `source` field does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding to the answer above by @neverwalkaloner

#### Many = True

`many=True` signals that there is more than one object (an iterable) being passed to the serializer. Passing this field in turn triggers the `many_init` within `BaseSerializer` to automagically create a `ListSerializer` instance.

Source Code Snippet:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    # We override this method in order to automagically create
    # `ListSerializer` classes instead when `many=True` is set.
    if kwargs.pop('many', False):
        return cls.many_init(*args, **kwargs)
    return super(BaseSerializer, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### Source = "xyz"

This tells DRF which object attribute supplies the value for the field. The default assumption is that the field name declared on the serializer is the same as the field on the object instance that supplies the value. In cases where this is not true, `source` allows you to explicitly supply the object instance where the serializer will look for the value. Here's a peek into the `def bind(self, field_name, parent)` inside `serializers.fields` where this happens

Source Code Snippet:

```
    # self.source should default to being the same as the field name.
    if self.source is None:
        self.source = field_name

    # self.source_attrs is a list of attributes that need to be looked up
    # when serializing the instance, or populating the validated data.
    if self.source == '*':
        self.source_attrs = []
    else:
        self.source_attrs = self.source.split('.')
```

Finally the value is gotten as follows using the `source` and `source_attrs` declared in `bind`:

```
def get_attribute(self, instance):
    """
    Given the *outgoing* object instance, return the primitive value
    that should be used for this field.
    """
    try:
        return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
    except (KeyError, AttributeError) as exc:
```

Assuming a `Question` can have multiple `Answers`, your approach is correct.

The problem appears to be that the source you supplied is the `RelatedManager` instance itself, and not the queryset of `Answer` objects. I assumed DRF resolves this accurately, can you try changing it to source='answer_set.all'.

`answer_set` is the default `RelatedManager` name given by Django. It might be wise to name your backward relationship using related_name in the Django model. This can be achieved by changing:

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='answers')
```

Comment: it seems like this is only needed for one to many relations incase there is a one to one relation there is no need to specify the many and source field provided the name of the field used in the serializer is same as in the model. Am I correct ?

Comment: Assuming a question can have multiple answers, your approach is correct. The problem is that yhe source you supposed  is the manager and not the query set of answers. Change it to `source='answer_set.all'`. It might be wise to name your backward relationship using `related_name` in the django model.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not the best explanation and someone can add more details but briefly `many=True` tells to serializer that it will take list of objects for serilizing proccess. In other words it's just a trigger that allows you to specify will you serialize, well, *many* objects at once, or just *single* object.

`source` on the other side specify which attribute of objects should be serializing with current serializer's field.

In practice this line

```
answers = EmbeddedAnswerSerializer(many=True, source='answer_set')
```

means that you want to serialize `answer_set` attribute of `Question` object with `EmbeddedAnswerSerializer`. Since `answer_set` **is list of object you should add** `many=True` as argument to make serializer aware that it will work with list of objects instead of single object.