# What does 'many = True' do in Django Rest FrameWork?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am learning DRF now, im little puzzuled by this `many = True` code. What does it do? Or what does it mean?

example 1

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

example 2

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

    def list(self, request):
        # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)?

Comment: Check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976679/need-help-understanding-many-and-source-fields-in-a-serializer/

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah sir , have read it that's why i am getting confused in serializer relationship  its written `many - If applied to a to-many relationship, you should set this argument to True.` 

then in serializers its written `To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the many=True` ... one code but two different explanations is making me confused..

Comment: What's different about those explanations? The both say that if you have multiple objects, set it to true.

Answer (score 52):

I think you are confusing `many=True` with many to many realtionship, but the concepts is not like that

by setting `many=True` you tell drf that queryset contains mutiple items (a list of items) so drf needs to serialize each item with serializer class (and `serializer.data` will be a list)

if you don't set this argument it means queryset is a single instance and `serializer.data` will be a single object)